# What is the difference between hook and callback?

Tags: callback, hook

By reading some text, especially the iOS document about delegate, all the protocol method are called **hook** that the custom delegate object need to implement. But some other books, name these **hook** as **callback**, what is the difference between them? Are they just different name but the same mechanism? In addition to Obj-C, some other programming languages, such as C, also got the **hook**, same situation with Obj-C?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The terminology here is a bit fuzzy.  In general the two attempt to achieve similar results.

In general, a *callback* is a function (or delegate) that you register with the API to be called at the appropriate time in the flow of processing (e.g to notify you that the processing is at a certain stage)

A *hook* traditionally means something a bit more general that serves the purpose of modifying calls to the API (e.g. modify the passed parameters, monitor the called functions).  In this meaning it is usually much lower level than what can be achieved by higher-level languages like Java.

In the context of *iOS*, the word *hook* means the exact same thing as *callback* above

Answer (score 27):

Let me chime in with a Javascript answer. In Javascript, **callbacks**, **hooks** and **events** are all used. In this order, they are each higher level concepts than the other.

Unfortunately, they are often used improperly which leads to confusion.

### Callbacks

From a control flow perspective, a **callback** is a function, usually given as an argument, that you execute before returning from your function.

This is usually used in asynchoronous situations when you need to wait for I/O (e.g. HTTP request, a file read, a database query etc.). You don't want to wait with a synchronous `while` loop, so other functions can be executed in the meantime.

When you get your data, you (permanently) relinquish control and call the callback with the result.

```js
function myFunc(someArg, callback) {
    // ...
    callback(error, result);
}
```

Because the callback function may be some code that hasn't been executed yet, and you don't know what's above your function in the call stack, generally instead of throwing errors you pass on the error to the callback as an argument. There are *error-first* and *result-first* callback conventions.

Mostly callbacks have been replaced by [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) in the Javascript world and since ES2017+, you can natively use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to get rid of callback-rich spaghetti code and make asynchronous control flow look like it was synchronous.

Sometimes, in special cascading control flows you run callbacks in the middle of the function. E.g. in [Koa (web server) middleware](https://koajs.com/#cascading) or [Redux middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) you run `next()` which returns after all the other middlewares in the stack have been run.

### Hooks

Hooks are not really a well-defined term, but in Javascript practice, you provide hooks when you want a client (API/library user, child classes etc.) to take optional actions at well-defined points in your control flow.

So a hook may be some function (given as e.g. an argument or a class method) that you call at a certain point e.g. during a database update:

```js
data = beforeUpdate(data);

// ...update

afterUpdate(result);
```

Usually the point is that:

- Hooks can be optional
- Hooks usually are waited for i.e. they are there to modify some data
- There is at most one function called per hook (contrary to events)

React makes use of hooks in its [Hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), and they - quoting their definition - "are functions that let you “hook into” React state and lifecycle features", i.e. they let you change React state and also run custom functions each time when certain parts of the state change.

### Events

In Javascript, events are *emitted* at certain points in time, and clients can subscribe to them. The functions that are called when an event happens are called **listeners** - or for added confusion, **callbacks**. I prefer to shun the term "callback" for this, and use the term "listener" instead.

This is also a generic OOP pattern.

In front-end there's a [DOM interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) for events, in node.js you have the [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) interface. A sophisticated asynchronous version is implemented in [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/).

Properties of events:

- There may be multiple listeners/callbacks subscribed (to be executed) for the same event.
- They usually don't receive a callback, only some event information and are run synchronously
- **Generally, and unlike hooks**, they are not for modifying data inside the event emitter's control flow. The emitter doesn't care 'if there is anybody listening'. It just calls the listeners with the event data and then continues right away.

Examples: events happen when a data stream starts or ends, a user clicks on a button or modifies an input field.

Comment: I don't know if that `“hook into” React state and lifecycle features` part is gone in the doc, but still I was looking for such an explanation to compare callback and hook. By the way I think the title `Events` should be `Listeners` instead. And.. I found myself disliking how indefinite the definition of `hook` can be even to a medium level developer.

Answer (score 16):

The two term are very similar and are sometimes used interchangably.  A hook is an option in a library were the user code can link a function to change the behavior of the library.  The library function need not run concurrent with the user code; as in a destructor.

A callback is a specific type of hook where the user code is going to initiate the library call, usually an I/O call or GUI call, which gives contol over to the kernel or GUI subsystem.  The controlling process then 'calls back' the user code on an interupt or signal so the user code can supply the handler.

Historically, I've seen hook used for interupt handlers and callback used for GUI event handlers.  I also see hook used when the routine is to be static linked and callback used in dynamic code.

Comment: Great answer! I appreciate you hitting the various use cases and examples where you see the different uses, as this adds a lot of clarity to how the writers of APIs intend the two concepts to be used and understood.

Answer (score 5):

Two great answers already, but **I wanted to throw in one more piece of evidence the terms "hook" and "callback" are the same, and can be used interchangeably**: FreeRTOS favors the term "hook" but recognizes "callback" as an equivalent term, when they say:

> The idle task can optionally call an application defined **hook (or callback)** function - the idle hook.
>
> The tick interrupt can optionally call an application defined **hook (or callback)** function - the tick hook.
>
> The memory allocation schemes implemented by heap_1.c, heap_2.c, heap_3.c, heap_4.c and heap_5.c can optionally include a malloc() failure **hook (or callback)** function that can be configured to get called if pvPortMalloc() ever returns NULL.

Source: https://www.freertos.org/a00016.html

Answer (score 0):

Although many people use the term somewhat interchangeably, and the form they take look similar to each other, there is a core difference: what it is intended to do.

Here is an excerpt from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75656782/2828100) that goes into detail about hooks vs. event listeners vs. callbacks.

> Hooks are functions that are invoked when a certain step occurs. It should naturally imply that there are well-defined steps in the function that invokes the hooks, or well-defined states if those hooks are attached to a state machine.

> Callbacks should be all about returning and resuming control. When we make a function call that does some I/O, we use callbacks to resume the program where it left off. As such, functions that take a callback parameter are naturally amenable to changing them into functions that return a promise--i.e. async functions.

Apple notoriously conflates everything to "delegates" so I understand the confusion. However, think of **hooks** more like `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`, only the implementation of those hooks are handed over to an instance other than the `UIViewController`. On the other hand, **callbacks** are the parameters usually named `completions` or `completionHandler`s in Apple development.