# What are the lifecycle hooks in React? When they are used?

Tags: reactjs

I used **React** about 3 months.

However, I still don't
understand lifecycle hooks and how they work in React. I usually `setState` in various methods and not lifecycle hooks. Thus the question - how are different React lifecycle hooks used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lifecycle in React usually refers to [the lifecycle of a component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle), it's expressively portrayed on [this diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) (React 16.4):

[image: lifecycle diagram]

The thing the question refers to are lifecycle [hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467557/what-is-meant-by-the-term-hook-in-programming). They are component class methods that are expected to be called by the framework itself at some moment, all of them are listed in respective [reference section](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle). Lifecycle hooks aren't expected to be called by a developer; even if this can be done, this will have code smell. The only place where lifecycle hooks should be called manually are tests.

While [`React.Component` non-lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#other-apis) (`setState` and `forceUpdate`) and user methods are supposed to be called explicitly.