# Why does pytest.main returns an int or an exit code

Tags: pytest, type-hinting

pytest.main is supposedly returning an integer or an ExitCode according to the type-hinting of its source code.
I don't understand in what situation would an integer be returned. I only get Exitcodes (ExitCode.OK, etc.).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a look at Pytest's [source code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/src/_pytest/config/__init__.py#L165), we can see that the integers come from this line:

```py
ret: Union[ExitCode, int] = config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(config=config)
```

This is the return code from Pytest plugins: Pytest will try running that hook for all the loaded plugins and return the first non-`None` result. You can see an [example in the help/version hook](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/src/_pytest/helpconfig.py#L147-L156).

I'm guessing that an integer was the expected type for this hook in the earliest versions of Pytest, since the `ExitCode` class dates [from Pytest 5](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/src/_pytest/config/__init__.py#L89). Integers also allow Pytest plugins to return various exit codes without being constrained by Pytest's own `ExitCode`.

You can read more on [Pytest plugins](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_plugins.html#writing-plugins) and the [Pytest hook reference](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#hook-reference).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the notion of `hook`?

Comment: Basically, it's an extension point of Pytest, that allows Pytest plugins to add behavior when some event occurs, in this case, when Pytest is invoked. See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467557/what-is-meant-by-the-term-hook-in-programming).

Comment: Thank you. And the example you mentioned is one of the many hooks that could be run when Pytest is invoked?

Comment: Exactly. However, `pytest_cmdline_main` is the only hook that can directly influence the return code of Pytest. Other hooks are triggered by other events, such as ["CTRL-C" was pressed](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_keyboard_interrupt) or [a warning was encountered](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_warning_recorded)

Comment: So when creating pytest plugins, people can change the behaviour by changing what pytest_cmdline_main does basically? Just making sure I got it right.

Comment: That's right: a plugin that implements its own `pytest_cmdline_main` can, among other things, add new flags or commands in Pytest and return arbitrary exit codes. I'm no expert, but that is what I understood from the code.